# Why does my PC micro-freeze every second?

Tags: windows-10, memory, freeze

For around a year, my computer randomly has micro-freezes that last for ~100ms every second, mainly when I play Minecraft using Google Chrome or Android Studio. During the micro-freeze, there is an odd sound like a sort of sizzle, and the only way to stop these micro-freezes is to restart my laptop.

What is the cause of these micro-freezes? Is it the RAM? How can I avoid having them?

Comment: What do you think is the source of that odd sound? Does it come from the built-in speakers or do you think it's coming from some other place like may be HDD (if you have one in your laptop)?To begin with, in Google chrome settings try disabling 'Use hardware acceleration when available'. Run Memtest and check if it reports any Memory Errors. Check if all device drivers are up-to-date, else try updating them.  Do mention complete hardware config of your laptop. Check if anything gets recorded in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Well, the odd sounds appears when there is something currently playing (like a YouTube video), but if there is no sound or the sound is off, I don't hear anything. So I guess it comes from the speaker. I've updated every drivers on my laptop, but this didn't do anything special, and most of them were already up to date.